# Unable to decode JSON body for Falcon tests in Python

Tags: python, pytest, falconframework

I'm trying to write some pytests for the Falcon framework and am following the instructions [here](http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/testing.html). I want to simulate a POST request. However, I keep getting the following error

> tests/test_app.py:29: 
>   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ../../harvester-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/falcon/testing/client.py:170:
>   in json
>       return json.loads(self.text) /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py:338:
>   in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s) /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py:366:
>   in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>
> ---
>
> self = , s = '', idx =
>   0
>
> ```
> def raw_decode(self, s, idx=0):
>     """Decode a JSON document from ``s`` (a ``str`` or ``unicode``
>         beginning with a JSON document) and return a 2-tuple of the Python
>         representation and the index in ``s`` where the document ended.
>
>         This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may
>         have extraneous data at the end.
>
>         """
>     try:
>         obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>     except StopIteration:
> ```
>
> > ```
> >       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") E           ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
> > ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py:384:
>   ValueError

Here is the Falcon test I am attempting to write. When I validate the JSON I put in the `data` variable on [JSONlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) it shows me the data is valid so the issue doesn't seem to be with the formatting.

```
import json

import pytest
from falcon import testing

from harvester.app import api


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    return testing.TestClient(api)


def test_elasticsearch_endpoint(client):
    data = {
        "Type": "SubscriptionConfirmation",
        "MessageId": "0a069ec4-2e6f-4436-9f1d-aa55c3b048f9",
        "Token": "2336412f37fb68751e6e241d59b68cb9ca332001818266bdd4984dd60a76ff2c8a43220b28241ad0ae6659d6313bb2336e98d19bdbc52e0c99578ad43934324b5e73a20e9ad517741cf14a57793d052e9986038ee688a059b34e49746d106bcd597f18f7ff3560be204ef8cd339a3c5276bfa3cc784a7904c8720519387a0",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:141592612890",
        "SubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:141592612890:harvester_test&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d59b68cb9ca332001818266bdd4984dd60a76ff2c8a41ad0ae6659d6313bb2336e98d19bdbc52e0c99578ad43934324b5e73a20e9ad517741cf14a57793d052e9986038ee688a059b34e49746d106bcd597f18f7ff3560be204ef8cd339a3c5276bfa3cc784a7904c8720519387a0",
        "Timestamp": "2017-06-01T13:22:49.849Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "Pj9F8PrgqPkSuLjHtrJ9pmh3ZH3kZBaLs5Ywx1C0rrOc4PJp3hYiria9SZr1Xm8uE549khxDFIdAsnGee9fSeO7tZWSNI3W3gRLVnIJ0uAjxU0oicj3P7NnGQ5kUnihKva//Q39RlZOIr4OsxTvOrXnag6M32aC3pEFdBaXJqO0iJJOokT+mmoWa9BWfHXnb/ORAigo50BXsVNSN92PRZAZ7qTeypZSU70EF1+vKNt7mbxrOE2/wpOtb7uDfg/ZW8yZQQqr100bnQVfStDSp6MzID+vupQhM2PR/gS84INA+VdOUhxll/kEkDE98tR9OrNz/PITts5XSg==",
        "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-b95095beb82e8f6a04.pem"
    }
    result = client.simulate_post('/v1/track/analytics', body=json.dumps(data))
    print result.json
```

Any clue why this occurs?

Comment: How did you fix this? I have tried all the answer here but non worked

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to set the {"Content-Type": "application/json"} in your header.

Also, the way you're sending your payload could be adjusted as below:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = urlencode({
        "Type": "SubscriptionConfirmation",
        "MessageId": "0a069ec4-2e6f-4436-9f1d-aa55c3b048f9",
        "Token": "2336412f37fb68751e6e241d59b68cb9ca332001818266bdd4984dd60a76ff2c8a43220b28241ad0ae6659d6313bb2336e98d19bdbc52e0c99578ad43934324b5e73a20e9ad517741cf14a57793d052e9986038ee688a059b34e49746d106bcd597f18f7ff3560be204ef8cd339a3c5276bfa3cc784a7904c8720519387a0",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:141592612890",
        "SubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:141592612890:harvester_test&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d59b68cb9ca332001818266bdd4984dd60a76ff2c8a41ad0ae6659d6313bb2336e98d19bdbc52e0c99578ad43934324b5e73a20e9ad517741cf14a57793d052e9986038ee688a059b34e49746d106bcd597f18f7ff3560be204ef8cd339a3c5276bfa3cc784a7904c8720519387a0",
        "Timestamp": "2017-06-01T13:22:49.849Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "Pj9F8PrgqPkSuLjHtrJ9pmh3ZH3kZBaLs5Ywx1C0rrOc4PJp3hYiria9SZr1Xm8uE549khxDFIdAsnGee9fSeO7tZWSNI3W3gRLVnIJ0uAjxU0oicj3P7NnGQ5kUnihKva//Q39RlZOIr4OsxTvOrXnag6M32aC3pEFdBaXJqO0iJJOokT+mmoWa9BWfHXnb/ORAigo50BXsVNSN92PRZAZ7qTeypZSU70EF1+vKNt7mbxrOE2/wpOtb7uDfg/ZW8yZQQqr100bnQVfStDSp6MzID+vupQhM2PR/gS84INA+VdOUhxll/kEkDE98tR9OrNz/PITts5XSg==",
        "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-b95095beb82e8f6a04.pem"
})

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
result = client.simulate_post('/v1/track/analytics', body=data, headers=headers)
```

Then, this should fix the issue.
Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Falcon. but taking a wild guess here:
in your fixture you just pass api class/function definition but you are not calling `api()` or calling `api.create()`. Try:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    return testing.TestClient(api())  # or api.create() ?
```

Also error you posted points to the line 29 but the code snippet you posted only contains 27 lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's the call to `result.json` rather than your POSTed JSON that is triggering the validation error. Presumably the elasticsearch endpoint you're testing is sending back a non-JSON error document.

https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/master/falcon/testing/client.py#L153

The docs do say that `result.json` will throw an error if the results aren't parseable as JSON but this could definitely be clearer!

http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/testing.html#falcon.testing.Result.json